# QT Phonon is not seekable once an Effect is used

Tags: c++, qt, effect, phonon

I have used QT Phonon to play audio file.
The problem is that i need the ability to change the play rate, while keeping the ability to seek the file.

It seems from test that once you add the Phonon speed Effect,  mediaObject.isSeekable becomes false.

Does anybody know how to use Phonon, while keeping seekable ability with the speed effect?

Here is some sample code to add a speed effect:

```cpp
QList<Phonon::EffectDescription> effectDescriptions =
        Phonon::BackendCapabilities::availableAudioEffects();
foreach(Phonon::EffectDescription effectDesc, effectDescriptions)
{
    if(effectDesc.name() == "speed")
    {
        speedEffect = new Phonon::Effect(effectDesc);
        path.insertEffect(speedEffect);

        QList<Phonon::EffectParameter> parameters = speedEffect->parameters();
        foreach(Phonon::EffectParameter param, parameters)
        {
            if(param.name() == "speed")
            {
                speedParameter = param;
            }
        }

        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you connect to `void MediaObject::seekableChanged ( bool isSeekable )` and check if the seekable state is changed?

Comment: i have connected to `void MediaObject::seekableChanged ( bool isSeekable )` . If i dont use the effect, this slot is called with value true. If i use the effect, this method is never called.